# HQL query join tables

Tags: java, hql

I am using hibernate to connect to my database for a project.

I would like to have a query that gets the products out of my database with the discription and name in a certain language. The parameter I have is the short name for the language, so first I would have to get the id of the language and then get the text in the required languages.

I have tried the following hql query, without success.

```
from Products as p
where p.productlanguages.languages.shortname like 'eng'
```

This is an image of the part of the database where the data should come from:
[image: database]

I have got the desired result with an sql query, but I can't seem to get it to work in hibernate. But I would prefer to do this in hql.

```
SELECT * FROM products p 
INNER JOIN productlanguage pl ON pl.Products_id = p.id 
WHERE pl.Languages_id = 
(
SELECT id FROM languages 
WHERE Shortname = 'eng'
);
```

Could anyone tell me how to build this hql query?
Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try below:

```
   from Products p INNER JOIN p.productlanguages pl
   where pl.languages.shortname ='eng'
```

I am assuming that you have mapped `Product-Productlanguages` relationship as `OneToMany` and `Productlanguages-Langages` relationship as `ManyToOne` as depicted in your E-R diagram.

**EDIT:** There seems to be a typo in `Productlanguage` mapping at line `public Languages getLanguages() {barcode`, remove the `barcode` in the end.

```
@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name="Languages_id", nullable=false, insertable=false, updatable=false)
public Languages getLanguages() {barcode

    return this.languages;
}
```

Comment: This works, but now I can't put the result in a Set<Product>.

Comment: @Jerodev: This should return `List<Product>` with unique product entities.

Comment: This is the code for my model: [http://pastebin.com/8aM5eKYx](http://pastebin.com/8aM5eKYx). Whenever I try the query you provided I get an error saying 'Unable to find method [getBarcode] with [0] parameters'.

Comment: @Jerodev: Are you using the above query as it is? I don't see any barcode in the query. In your mapping, you have mapped `barcode` as String so shouldn't be any problem. Share your query. Also share `Productlanguage` mapping.

Comment: Somehow the query creates another object which is not 'Products'.

This is the mapping for productlanguage: [http://pastebin.com/t981xjLH](http://pastebin.com/t981xjLH)

Comment: @Jerodev: Are you running the exactly same query as above?

Comment: @Jerodev: There seems to be a typo in your other mapping file. Please refer the edit in my answer. Is it compiling fine?

Comment: I don't see this typo in the code, where have you found this? The code compiles fine.

Comment: @Jerodev: Thes line: `public Languages getLanguages() {barcode`. Notice the barcode in the end.

Comment: @Jerodev: I don't see it anymore..strange. Back to your original issue.   CAn you please share the query and the error stack trace?